# What happens when there is more than one access right for the same object in ACL OpenErp?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

How does ACL behave when there is more than one access rights for the same object for the same group.

For example: There is two rights entries for the object 'partner' for the same group sale/manager, having different accesses.

res.partner.sale.manager      -     Partner        -      Sales / Manager

res.partner.crm.user         -          Partner     -        Sales / Manager

Which access right will be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group specific rules are combined together with logical OR,

(GROUP_1_RULE_1 OR GROUP_1_RULE_2) OR (GROUP_2_RULE_1 OR GROUP_2_RULE_2)

while global rules are combined together with a logical AND operator.

GLOBAL_RULE_1 AND GLOBAL_RULE_2

and global rules as well as group specific rules are combined together like

GLOBAL_RULE_1 AND GLOBAL_RULE_2 AND ( (GROUP_1_RULE_1 OR GROUP_1_RULE_2) OR (GROUP_2_RULE_1 OR GROUP_2_RULE_2) ).

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You get access to an object if an ACL exists granting it.

In other words, the permissions will be the result of joining the multiple ACL rules with an OR union operation (and not by using an AND intersection operator).